# Export interface as Partial<OtherInterface>

Tags: typescript

I have an interface defined like below:

```js
export interface Iface {
   id: string;
   foo: string;
}
```

I want to create an interface that's a partial of `Iface` and export it. I tried

```js
export interface PartialIface = Partial<Iface>;
```

but typescript complains of a partial error. If I change the `interface` keyword to `type` it works. How come I have to declare it as a `type` alias and not an `interface`?

```js
export type PartialIface = Partial<Iface>;
```

Comment: If you want to use `interface` instead of `type` for whatever reason, you can `export interface PartialIface extends Partial<Iface> {};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look:

```js
export interface Iface {
   id: string;
   foo: string;
}

export type PartialFace=Partial<Iface>
```

Also You can copy paste your interface and make all properties optional:

```js
export interface Iface {
   id?: string;
   foo?: string;
}
```

I'm not aware about other approaches

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign Partial to an interface which is not possible. What you can do is assign to other entity to be Partial of your interface.

```
export interface Iface {
   id: string;
   name: string;
} 

const me: Partial<Iface> = {
  name: 'me-name'
 }
```

Basically, you can assign a type to another type and do what you wanted to do.